# batch rename 200000 files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I wish to rename 206,372 files the current name is `Minecraft (03)_206372.tga` that is how the files are labled.

I have an idea of what I'm doing but I want to be sure of what I'm doing.
I so far have a command

```
ls Minecraft\ \(03)\)_206372.tga | awk -F'_' '{print $2}'
```

The command will print `206372.tga`.
That does what I want, but I want to change the name of a little over 200,000 files with the command at the same time, can someone please help finish the command.

Comment: What's the structure of where the files are located? Most likely you're just going to have some [tag:find] and doing `${file##*_}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for file in Minecraft*.tga ; do 
    mv "$file" "${file##*_}"
done
```

Comment: @WhitequillRiclo You’re welcome. Glad it worked out for you. :)

Comment: @jaypal singh could you possibly explain `${file##*_}`? step by step? thank you

Comment: @MortezaLSC It is a `bash` parameter expansion. You can read more on it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `rename` command, which uses perl regexes.
`rename 's/Minecraft \(03\)_//' *.tga`
This replaces "Minecraft (03)_" with an empty string in all files ending with ".tga".

Comment: It says the argument list is too long

Comment: Sorry. I only tested it on a few files. (Stupid me)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little brute force, but understandable way to remove a prefix from your files:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$0
for file in `find $dir -name blah_\*.tga`; do
    newfile=`echo $file | sed 's/blah_//'`
    my $file $newfile
done
```

Depending on your file system, you may get a significant change in performance from having so many files in the directory and making so many changes.

Notes about using "find":

- If you need to use find and don't need to fully recurse, also you might want to add a "-maxdepth 1" option to the find,
- Also, find with a glob probably won't work because of the aggregate length of all file names would make a command line too long.

Comment: You shouldn't really use the `#!/bin/sh` shebang anymore, it varies way to much by system. Also I think most shells will try to buffer the output of [tag:find] which will almost certainly cause a buffer overflow for such a large number of files, need to add a `while/read` somewhere to read concurrently.

Comment: @BroSlow A shebang is a good way to show which shell the script is intended to target. I can't believe you are suggesting no shebang at all, so what shebang do you recommend in its place please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Think you missed my point. `#!/bin/sh` is not well defined, it will mean the bourne shell on some systems, dash on others, bash on yet others, etc...

Comment: So what would you have written please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Whatever `ctschuster` really means (most likely [tag:bash]), unless he is actually using the bourne shell, which seems unlikely.